# Unity Camera Change Affects ability to click on object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm building a game where it's first person perspective, except when I'm destroying a box, and then it's third person.

The box that's being destroyed needs to be punched 3x (aka clicked 3x) to be fully destroyed. The camera change works on the first punch, but after that it's not registering any clicks when it returns to the first person camera, and it works fully when there is no camera change. It's on mobile. Can anyone help me?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Fist : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject fistScript;
    public bool isBroken = false;
    int count = 4;
    GameObject piece1;
    GameObject piece2;
    GameObject piece3;
    GameObject piece4;
    bool inTrigger;
    public GameObject rubble;
    public GameObject zone;
    Animator anim;
    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject firstPersonCam;
    public GameObject thirdPersonCam;

    private void Start()
    {
        piece1 = rubble.transform.Find("1").gameObject;
        piece2 = rubble.transform.Find("2").gameObject;
        piece3 = rubble.transform.Find("3").gameObject;
        piece4 = rubble.transform.Find("4").gameObject;
        zone = rubble.transform.Find("FistTriggerZone").gameObject;
        anim = player.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        // chainsaw is on
        if (fistScript.GetComponent<FistOn>().fistOn == true)
        {
            //set zone active
            zone.SetActive(true);
            //set trigger inactive if in trigger so that it can register click on object
            if (inTrigger)
            {
                zone.SetActive(false);
            }
            else if (!inTrigger)
            {
                zone.SetActive(true);
            }
        // chainsaw is off
        } 
        else 
        {
            zone.SetActive(false);
        }

        //if it's not broken yet
        if (!isBroken)
        {
            DestroyBlock();
        } 
        else 
        {
            zone.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    public void DestroyBlock()
    {
        RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
        for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i) 
        {
           if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase.Equals(TouchPhase.Began)) 
           {
                // Construct a ray from the current touch coordinates
                Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(i).position);
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) 
                {
                    if (hit.transform.name == "1" || hit.transform.name == "2" || hit.transform.name == "3" || hit.transform.name == "4")
                    {
                        if (fistScript.GetComponent<FistOn>().fistOn == true)
                        {
                            if (count == 4)
                            {
                                StartCoroutine(SwitchCamera());
                                Destroy(piece1);
                            } 
                            else if (count == 3)
                            {
                                StartCoroutine(SwitchCamera());
                                Destroy(piece2);
                            } 
                            else if (count == 2)
                            {
                                StartCoroutine(SwitchCamera());
                                Destroy(piece3);
                            } 
                            else if (count == 1)
                            {
                                StartCoroutine(SwitchCamera());
                                Destroy(piece4);
                                isBroken = true;
                            }
                            count-=1;
                        }
                        anim.SetInteger("action",0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter()
    {
        inTrigger = true;
    }

    void OnTriggerExit()
    {
        inTrigger = false;
    }

    private IEnumerator SwitchCamera()
    {
        firstPersonCam.SetActive(false);
        thirdPersonCam.SetActive(true);
        anim.SetInteger("action", 6);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

        firstPersonCam.SetActive(true);
        thirdPersonCam.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you compare the two cameras .. do you have the same components attached?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is right here:

```
// Construct a ray from the current touch coordinates
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(i).position);
```

You are projecting your touch to world space using Camera.main and not your currently active camera. You want to be doing something like:

```
thirdPersonCam.GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(i).position);
```

An additional note is that you should be avoiding using Camera.main and GetComponent<>() in the Update() function as these are both very slow and shouldn't be done every frame.

If you need references to these things, if possible you should move them into their own variables and assign them in the Start() function or somewhere else that isn't happening every frame.

EDIT: For clarification Camera.main does not refer to the camera that is currently rendering or on top of the others, it is simply the first camera that Unity finds with the tag "Main Camera" on it.

Personally I think that it should be depricated as it leads to many misconceptions and a lot of slow code being written.